# How to stop the generation of random indexes every time the page reloads?

Tags: javascript, node.js

A `NodeJs` based quiz app where the admin adds the question. Got random unique indexes for those questions, but every time the page reloads, these indexes change:

```
router.get('/start',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res) => {
  Question.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$Category",ques:{$push:"$$ROOT"},count:{$sum:1}}}],(err,data)=>{
    Test.find({},(err,doc) => {
      var username=req.user.email;
      var quesarray = [];
      for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0;j<doc[0].selectcategory.length;j++) {
            if(data[i]._id === doc[0].selectcategory[j]) {
              var set = new Set();

              while(set.size < Number(doc[0].questioncount[j])) {
                  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * data[i].count);
                  set.add(x);
              }

              var a = [...set];
              console.log(data[i]._id);
              quesarray = [...quesarray,[...set]];
              console.log(a);
            } 
        }
      }
      var catg = [...doc[0].selectcategory];

      var set = new UserQset({
          username,
          catg,
          quesarray
      });

      set.save((err)=>{
        if(!err) {
            console.log("done");
        }
      })
      res.render('newfile',{
          set,
          data,
          doc
      })
    })
  })
})
```

How do I stop the changing of indexes on page reload?

Comment: Are you trying to make the number array you store in `set` be the same every time the route is accessed?

Comment: Yes, but i solved the problem by re routeing it to another path